# Why NSString variable needs to be retained?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, retain, autorelease

I have the following code in my **.h** file:

```
@interface Utils : NSObject {
    NSString *dPath;
}    
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *dPath;
```

And in my **.m** file:

```
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
dPath = [[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName];
[dPath retain];
```

Why do I have to **retain** *dPath* if it's already defined as (nonatomic, **retain**)?
If I don't add the [dPath retain]; I get some strange, random errors and the application crashes  when using this variable in other functions. I guess that's because of some *autorelease* somehere but I don't have any.

So, what is the (nonatomic, **retain**) doing anyway? Is it really necessary the [dPath retain]; or am I just hiding something else with that?

Comment: If you set dPath inside Utils make sure you are using self.dPath, not just dPath

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the code isn't calling the `dPath` property's setter method, it's just setting the instance variable `dPath` directly:

```
dPath = [[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName];
[dPath retain];
```

So it has to be retained manually.

You will be able to (in fact you need to) omit the `retain` call if the property setter was used like this (notice the `self.`):

```
self.dPath = [[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName];
```

or like this (notice the `setDPath:`):

```
[self setDPath:[[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName]];
```

The setter retains the `NSString` for you so you don't have to do it yourself.

---

A nice little practice to follow in order to avoid the confusion, is to affix an underscore to your ivar name to indicate it's an ivar:

```
    NSString *dPath_;
```

Then synthesize your property like this, to associate it with your differently-named ivar:

```
// self.dPath is the property, dPath_ is the ivar
@synthesize dPath = dPath_;
```

Then modify your `dealloc` method, as well as any other code that directly references the instance var, to use the affixed name instead:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [dPath_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I've just changed the code as you suggested and... it's working. No crashes till now. I guess I need to go back to objective-c basic stuff :(  Thank you!!

Comment: @KVron: You're welcome! You can always refer to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) again whenever you get stuck. Remember to mark an answer as accepted by clicking the hollow checkmark by the answer.

Comment: Also it's good practice to use copy instead of retain on NSString properties. The reason is NSMutableString can easily be assigned to a NSString without a compiler warning and then changed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try setting and getting it with

```
self.dPath
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the property setter method, which will invoke the retain, then you want to write:

```
self.dPath = ...
```

Jamming stuff into a variable with:

```
dPath = ...
```

completely ignores the properties of this instance variable.  Which is why you ended up needing to do the retain manually.